# "Unauthorized" exception by Simple.OData.Client by accessing the SharePoint REST API with valid credentials from Xamarin PCL

Tags: xamarin, sharepoint-api, simple.odata

Before I used *Simple.OData.Client* in our *Xamarin* project, I tried it with help of *LINQPad*. I was very impressed by the easiness to use it. When I built it into our *Xamarin* project I got exception by trying to get data from *SharePoint*'s REST Api.

> Simple.OData.Client.WebRequestException: Unexpected WebException
>   encountered ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error
>   writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decr...{Simple.OData.Client.WebRequestException: Unexpected
>   WebException encountered ---> System.Net.WebException: Error:
>   SendFailure (Error writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException:
>   Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication
>   or decryption has failed. --->
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received
>   from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010a

As I believe, this exception was caused by the fact that our *SharePoint* instance using self-signed certificate. I tried it to eliminate by returning always true to the *ServerCertificateValidationCallback*

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Now I get all the time *Unauthorized* exception from the Simple.OData.Client

> Simple.OData.Client.WebRequestException: Unauthorized

Initial call is from *MainViewModel* through the business layer

```
    private async void InitializeAsync()
    {
        // TODO [Anton Kalcik - Dienstag, 05. Mai 2015 17:09:55]: Show loading indicator
        TaskEntity getTaskForCurrentMonthAsyncTask = await _taksBusinessLayer.GetTaskForCurrentMonthAsync();
        _timeToDisplay = getTaskForCurrentMonthAsyncTask.DueDate - DateTime.Now;
        // TODO [Anton Kalcik - Dienstag, 05. Mai 2015 17:10:04]: Hide loading indicator

        StartCountdownTimer();
    }
```

The class which executing the call is the class *SharePointTaskRepository*

```
public class SharePointTaskRepository : ITaskRepository
{
    private readonly string _collectionName;
    private readonly ODataClient _oDataClient;

    public SharePointTaskRepository(Uri sharepointUri, string collectionName, ICredentials credentials)
    {
        if (sharepointUri == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sharepointUri");
        }
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(collectionName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Argument can't be null, empty or white space!", "collectionName");
        }
        if (credentials == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("credentials");
        }

        _collectionName = collectionName;

        var oDataClientSettings = new ODataClientSettings(sharepointUri, credentials);
        _oDataClient = new ODataClient(oDataClientSettings);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TaskModel>> ReadAsync(Expression<Func<TaskModel, bool>> filter, Expression<Func<TaskModel, object>> orderBy, int numberOfResults)
    {
        return await _oDataClient
                    .For<TaskModel>(_collectionName)
                    .Filter(filter)
                    .OrderBy(orderBy)
                    .Top(numberOfResults)
                    .FindEntriesAsync();
    }
}
```

I double checked the credentials, which are definitely correct. The code which utilize *ServerCertificateValidationCallback* is in the *ApplicationRuntimeSettings*. This class is platform specific, singleton and provided as all other objects by dependency injection.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ApplicationRuntimeSettings))]
namespace AZeitReminder.Droid.Infrastructure
{
    public class ApplicationRuntimeSettings : ApplicationRuntimeSettingsBase
    {
        public ApplicationRuntimeSettings()
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
        }

        public override SQLiteConnection CreateSqLiteConnection()
        {
                string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, DatabaseFileName);
                var currentPlatform = new SQLitePlatformAndroid();
                var connection = new SQLiteConnection(currentPlatform, path);

                return connection;
        }

        public override CultureInfo GetCultureInfo()
        {
            var androidLocale = Java.Util.Locale.Default;
            var netLanguage = androidLocale.ToString().Replace("_", "-"); // NOTE [Anton Kalcik - Dienstag, 05. Mai 2015 17:21:10]: turns pt_BR into pt-BR
            return new CultureInfo(netLanguage);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set PreAuthenticate = false; for your request. Simple.ODataClient uses HttpClientHandler internally. This HttpClientHandler sets PreAuthenticate = true; but you can modify this handler in the OnApplyClientHandler and set the property to false. Try this in your code:

```cs
oDataClientSettings.OnApplyClientHandler = handler => handler.PreAuthenticate = false;
```

The reason is that your Sharepoint server can throw "Unauthorized" as a challenge response and the WebRequest would not answer to the challenge unless this property is false.